# ionic2 Unexpected value 'nvD3' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ng2-nvd3 module for graph. Below is the code

angular 2, ionic 2

```
import {nvD3} from "ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        nvD3,
...
})
```

I am getting below error. can anyone help me to resolve below error

```
[15:51:10]  lint finished in 1.04 s
[15:51:11]  ngc: Error: Unexpected value 'nvD3' declared by the module 'AppModule'
    at /Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14044:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14031:51)
    at /Users/..//node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12801:47
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at analyzeModules (/Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12800:17)
    at OfflineCompiler.analyzeModules (/Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12826:18)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:105:47)
    at codegen (/Users/…/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:7:81)
    at Object.main (/Users/..//node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:30:16)
```

Comment: Got the same problem. Could you fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, here is how I fixed it in my code:

```
...
import { Key } from "../../utils/key";

declare var setLanguage; //Makes sure this forcing of type (a hack) is here

@Component({
  selector:    "page-home",
  templateUrl: "home.html",
  providers: [Storage]
})

//declare var setLanguage; //NOT HERE

export class HomePage {
...
```

Comment: Problem may be due to code in another source file, I got same errors as him due to above bug in my code.   It is probably not his problem, but may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong

```
import {nvD3} from "ng2-nvd3/build/lib/ng2-nvd3";
```

Right

```
import { nvD3 } from 'ng2-nvd3';
```